# DateTimeParseException when parsing String to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, date, datetime, parsing, java-8

The following works perfectly:

```
String startDate = "2019-10-12T00:00:00.000-07:00"

LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate,
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

However, for the following code:

```
String startDate = "2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00"

LocalDateTime startDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(startDate,
    DateTimeFormatter.ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME);
```

I get an exception:

> throws 
>   `java.time.format.DateTimeParseException`: Text '2019-10-12T00:00:00.000 07:00' could not be parsed at index 23

Can someone help me understand what might be possibly wrong here?

Comment: Please take some time to familiarize with the editor and format your question properly, thanks.

Comment: Voting to close, can not reproduce. Create a [mcve]. Also, the error message does not line up with the code you show. The message has no `+` or `-` at the zone, but a *space*. It is highly likely that the error message comes from a code version which you do not show here. I.e. a version with a *space* in the message, instead of a `+` or `-`. Which is obviously wrong, since this part is meant to tell the time offset, so either `+` or `-` in relation.

Comment: I bet that the `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00` date string is a URL query string parameter, and the `+` is decoded to space, because the `+` should have been encoded as `%2B`. Only reason I can think of for why a `+` was converted to a space.

Comment: @Andreas It seems that you may post that as an answer if you like.

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

(A) As mentioned in comment by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas), the disappearance of your `+` character in error message is suspicious. You likely have a character encoding problem. We here do not have enough info to diagnose that.

(B) Use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `LocalDateTime`, to fit your data.

```
OffsetDateTime
.parse( "2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00" )
.toInstant()
.toString()
```

> 2019-10-11T17:00:00Z

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nj2Prv).

## `LocalDateTime` is the wrong class

The `LocalDateTime` class lacks any concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So it cannot, by definition, represent a moment. A [`LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) object is *not* a point on the timeline.

Yet your input string indicates an offset-from-UTC, the `+07:00` in `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00`. Your attempt to put this value in a `LocalDateTime` is a misfit, a [square peg in a round hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_peg_in_a_round_hole).

Never use `LocalDateTime` when you mean a specific moment, a specific point on the timeline. This class is almost never used in business-oriented apps for present or past moments. When making appointments in the future, this class should be used when you want the time-of-day to remain the same regardless of politicians redefining the region’s time zone.

## `OffsetDateTime`

Parse as an [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) object.

Your input string happens to comply fully with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard for textual date-time formats. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
String input = "2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

## UTC

To adjust to the wall-clock time of [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) (an offset of zero), call [`OffsetDateTime::withOffsetSameInstant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html#withOffsetSameInstant(java.time.ZoneOffset)). For your convenience, use the constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = odt.withOffsetSameInstant( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Or simply extract an object of the basic building-block class in *java.time*, an `Instant`. An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) is always in UTC, by definition.

```
Instant instant = odt.toInstant() ;
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

To see the same moment as viewed through the wall-clock time used by the people of a particular region (a time zone), apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = odt.atZoneSameInstant( z ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

I tried running both dates locally with the same parsing of the `LocalDateTime`, and they **both run correctly**.

I could recreate your same error by using a different date (note the *space* at the zone offset, instead of a `+` or `-`) `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000 07:00` instead of `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00`. Which is what your error message shows (but not what your code has).

Are you sure that the code version you show, which uses `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000+07:00`, is the actual version that produces the error? It looks like you have been using `2019-10-12T00:00:00.000 07:00`, which then leads to the error.

Comment: I am sending the string as a request param and using postman to test it. Can that be a possible cause of error. I should have mentioned that earlier.

Comment: Of course, @AnkitaSingh, you are correct. You need to URL encode the string.

Answer (score -2):

there is an extra zero in the startDateTime
use startDateTime = "2019-10-12T00:00:00.00+07:00"

Comment: Milliseconds are 3 digits (HH:mm:ss.SSS) because 1,000 milliseconds = 1 second

Comment: public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME
The ISO-like date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with offset and zone, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]'. see this documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME                           also                   https://dotnetcodr.com/2015/01/11/formatting-dates-in-java-8-using-datetimeformatter/        it does not required 3 digits time

Comment: The example provided ("10:15:30") is in the format "HH:mm:ss" there are no milliseconds in that example.

Comment: I am sending the string as a request param and using postman to test it. Can that be a possible cause of error. I should have mentioned that earlier. Can I attach screenshots here ?

Comment: I verified for request param = "2019-01-28T13:00:00.000+01:00" postman sends the date as "2019-01-28T13:00:00.000 01:00". That is the cause of error. If I run the API using Swagger it works fine.

Comment: `DateTimeFormatter ISO_ZONED_DATE_TIME` accepts anything from 0 through 9 decimals on the seconds. This is not the issue.